# Implement Redirection in C

Tags: shell

I am implementing a shell in C. But I have a problem with file redirection.
 My problem is the following. If I only type `cat filename`, my shell will display the file and return back to prompt waiting for next command. However, the shell will exit after running `cat < filename`. My code is attached.

```
 75 int callExternals(vector<string>& tokens){
 76   pid_t childPid;
 77
 78   char** cstrings = new char*[tokens.size() + 1];
 79   for (size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i){
 80     cstrings[i] = new char[tokens[i].size() + 1];
 81     strcpy(cstrings[i],tokens[i].c_str());
 82   }
 83   cstrings[tokens.size()] = NULL;
 84   switch (childPid=fork()){
 85     case -1:
 86       perror("Unable to fork a process");
 87       return -1;
 88     case 0:
 89       execvp(cstrings[0],cstrings);
 90       //_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 91     default:
 92       waitpid(childPid,NULL,0);
 93   }
 94   return 0;
 95 }
```

Part of file redirection implementation

```
 40     case 1:
 42       vector<string> cmmd;
 43       cout << "tokens size "<<tokens.size()<<endl;
 44       for (vector<string>::iterator titer = tokens.begin(); titer != tokens.end(); titer++){
 45         if (!(titer->compare("<"))) break;
 46         cmmd.push_back(*titer);
 48       }
 51       int fd = open(tokens[pos[0]+1].c_str(), O_RDONLY);
 52       dup2(fd, 0);
 53       close(fd);
 54       callExternals(cmmd);
 55   }
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: Why are you messing with the pre-fork shell process's file descriptors?

Comment: I might see what you are saying. Thank you.

Comment: My original purpose is trying to reuse the callExternals function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework problem...

From what I can tell, you are extracting the full command (without the "< filename") to execute, and you are trying to open a file descriptor with the file name after the "<".

The very next line, 51, makes no sense.

The problem is that once you find the location, you ignore it and are just using 'pos[0]', which is some external unrelated variable, to find the filename. You need to get the value of the token that follows "<" to get the filename.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to extract the command with arguments and filename afterward. Vector<int> pos stores location of '<', '>', ">>" or '|'. The pos vectors will tell me how many redirection symbols and pipe in the command line. And I will use pos to extract all the commands and the filename, if there is any. I messed up with fork. I closed STDIN_FILENO without purpose. Thank you for your answer.